# Switching between baked image texture and pre-bake materials

Tags: materials, baking

Let's use two separate multicolored 6-sided cube as an example. The normal baking workflow goes something like this:

1. Apply material to faces of object in edit mode, e.g., one color (one material) for each of the 12 face.
2. Unwrap both cube's 6 faces to a single new UV map
3. For each material, make a floating image texture node in the node editor, point to "out.png"
4. Bake material to image (output is in "out.png")
5. Apply new image texture to object by making a new material ("Baked_Material") with "out_diffuse.png" as base color
6. Select entire cube, apply "Baked_material" as the material for all 6 faces.

So the question is, after step 6 is done, now I want to edit just one of the cube's face materials. **Is there a way to switch back to the state of the blender file just after step 1**, so I can go through the baking process again without having to through all 12 textures and either dis/reconnecting nodes or reassigning materials?

Or is the workflow incorrect and this shouldn't be a problem?

Making source cube textures:
[image: Making Source Cube Textures]

After applying baked material, the original material-face mappings are gone:

[image: Baked Material]